# How to plasterboard half hollow wall with gas pipe running up it

Tags: drywall

I recently had a breast wall plasterboarded and skimmed, however the right side cheek of the wall wasn't done because of what was behind it. That wall has concrete on the left, hollow in the middle and on the right there is a big gas pipe running from bottom to top!

This will be easier to understand with pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm not really sure the best way to approach it, the plasterer who did the rest of the wall suggested some wooden battens running horizontally across the wall with the plasterboard stuck to them, the problem then will be there will be a gap between the external corner of the wall and the new plasterboard.

The final complication is that there is a valve sticking out the case pipe towards the bottom, so I would probably need to box this out of the plasterboard.

Anybody got any suggestions? Ideally looking for the simplest solution but i know in this case there probably isn't one!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I must be missing something but why didn't the plasterers extend that wall 3 or 4 inches and then add the battens running horizontally across the wall?  Then the valve would be recessed and you could build a small framed access panel.

Comment: I would call that an answer @jack, I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something but why didn't the plasterers extend that wall 3 or 4 inches and then add the battens running horizontally across the wall? Then the valve would be recessed and you could build a small framed access panel.

Comment: Good question, I don't really have the answer. Probably a bit late now anyway since what's done is done. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why late?  It's going to be more work and look much worse  to hack the rest of this. Bite the bullet and cut out the last 12" of the finished wall and wrap it around right.  You're going to be looking at this for a long time and it's gonna get to you if you don't do it right.. good luck

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Do you think i could put the battons in and plasterboard that small cheek wall and then get the rest of wall extended so it all lines up after?

Comment: @EdJones you could add two 2x4's  flat against the concrete and the finished wall about a half inch in to allow for the drywall. That will add about three inches to the finished wall.  Then add a 2x4 to the stud on the right of the cheek wall. Now toe nail some  2x4 battons between the two.  add the drywall and the access panel for the valve and add the three inch piece of drywall to the finished wall covering up the 2x4's.

Comment: thanks for the help, much appreciated!